# Can I increase the volume over 100 on Windows 10 like in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, audio, realtek-hd-audio

As far as I know, Windows 10 doesn't have this feature and I've checked Loudness Equalization, but it's still too low, and the audio drivers are up to date.

Are there any open-source software solutions, similar to ALSA, for Windows 10 that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would be device and driver dependent but my experience (Win 10 dual-boot with Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo Edge 15 laptop) is that the Windows volume range includes the above 100% range you see on Ubuntu. For example: 100% on Ubuntu corresponds to ~80% on Windows.

Check to see if you have any vendor-specific control panel in Windows that might be limiting your audio volume.

Comment: I've already checked and no